# How to avoiding multiple for loops and reduce time?

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, nested-loops

Below are the 2 groups where I want to find if both group elements are present in one solr record. Currently 
 for example I have given 9 items in each groups and 3 solr records. But this is dynamic (it may be huge). I have tried with 3 for loops like mentioned below. For small set of records and group elements it is not an issue but if the record/group element count is huge it is taking huge amount of time to finish. Please let me know if any options are there to fix this.

Can I use **multiprocess** in this case ?

```
group1_items = ["group1_item1","group1_item2","group1_item3","group1_item4","group1_item5","group1_item6","group1_item7","group1_item8","group1_item9"]
group2_items = ["group2_item10","group2_item20","group2_item30","group2_item40","group2_item50","group2_item60","group2_item70","group2_item80","group2_item90"]
solrrecordset = [{"groupitems":"group1_item1,group2_item40,group3_itme200"},{"groupitems":"group1_item5,group2_item10,group3_itme300"},{"groupitems":"group3_item556,group4_item105,group5_itme306"}]

groupsets = {}
for eachitem in group1_items:
    for eachitem2 in group2_items:
         for eachrec in solrrecordset:
             if eachitem in eachrec["groupitems"].split(",") and eachitem2 in eachrec["groupitems"].split(","):
                 if eachitem+"|"+eachitem2 in groupsets:
                     groupsets[eachitem+"|"+eachitem2] += 1
                 else:
                     groupsets[eachitem+"|"+eachitem2] = 1
```

Comment: So what are you actually trying to do? Could it possibly be solved by indexing a value and faceting across that value instead?

Comment: Planning to show some comparison reports. We cant use facet because as I know facet is high memory consuming.

Comment: That depends on many factors; in general you're doing the exact same thing as a facet would do in your code, just inefficiently. Implement a facet, _and if it's a problem with memory usage_, evaluate your options from there. Don't start by assuming that (a function might be ideal for your use case isn't going to work :-)